# WPF AttachedProperty to close window and act on it in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, attached-properties

I am trying to redirect the Window `Closed` event to my ViewModel, but lack the proper hands on experience with AttachedProperties.

The class that holds the `AttachedProperty`

```
public class WindowClosedBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClosedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Closed",
        typeof (ICommand),
        typeof (WindowClosedBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(ClosedChanged));

    private static void ClosedChanged(
        DependencyObject target,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = target as Window;

        if (window != null)
        {
            // ??
        }
    }

    public static void SetClosed(Window target, ICommand value)
    {
        target.SetValue(ClosedProperty, value);
    }
}
```

How can I implement the behavior so that it will close the window and trigger the `RelayCommand`?

---

The (stripped) ViewModel :

```
    public RelayCommand WindowClosedCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainCommandsViewModel()
    {
        WindowClosedCommand = new RelayCommand(WindowClosedCommandOnExecuted, WindowClosedCommandOnCanExecute);
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TvShowManager.UserInterface.Views.MainWindow"

        <!-- left out irrelevant parts -->
        xmlns:closeBehaviors="clr-namespace:TvShowManager.UserInterface.CloseBehaviors"
        closeBehaviors:WindowClosedBehavior.Closed="{Binding WindowCloseCommand}" >
```

I simply bind a `RelayCommand` (WindowCloseCommand) to the attached property.

---

I tried debugging through this to get better understanding and hopefully figure out how to proceed, but no breakpoints are being hit in the class that holds my attached property. If anybody can explain why my code in `WindowClosedBehavior` never gets executed I would also greatly appreciate the advice there.

I hope it's clear what I am trying to achieve and that somebody can help me out.

Many thanks

Comment: just curious: Why don't you directly bind to WindowCloseCommand and achieve the desired result?

Comment: @WQad, which property are you suggesting to bind to the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `ClosedChanged` callback, just store the command and register an event handler to the window's `Closed` event to invoke the command:

```
private static ICommand _command;

private static void ClosedChanged(
    DependencyObject target,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = target as Window;

        if (window != null)
        {
            _command = e.NewValue as ICommand;
            window.Closed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (_command != null)
                    _command.Execute(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

In addition, you might want to un-register all previously existing event handlers on the window's `Closed` event, but that is only necessary if you plan to change the `WindowClosedBenahior` during runtime.

Comment: No need to store the value when attached property itself points to ICommand.

Comment: I will give this a try. Well, I already did, but something is still not setup properly because while debugging nothing seems to happen... The setter of the attached property never is executed, nor is the command. I will let you know how things work out. Thanks for the tips so far (and for the sort of acknowledgment that this should work!)

Comment: Don't be confused if the breakpoint inside the DependencyProperty's setter is not reached, since WPF doesn't call the setter when using Binding but uses some reflection logic instead. When adding a breakpoint to the first line of the `ClosedChanged` callback, is that reached?

Comment: Oh, and one more thing: The command in the Viewmodel is called `WindowClosedCommand`, but in XAML you're binding to `WindowCloseCommand` without a *d* - maybe this is the reason the command is not invoked? When I copy your code to an empty project, include my event handler solution, and correct the typo, it works and the command method is called after closing the window!

Comment: You are a star! Thx for the help on all three parts :). This answer deserves more upvotes!